MissingPluginException when using flutter_sound in flutter_foreground_task
I have to implement a feature where the user's microphone is recorded via the flutter_sound package's FlutterSoundRecorder and immediately played back through the speaker with a FlutterSoundPlayer for Android and iOS. I already accomplished this part of the task.
The recording and immediate playback has to happen in a separate isolate and should continue to happen even when the application is minimized/ unfocused and also when the smartphone enters its sleep mode.
The package flutter_foreground_task seemed very promising. I tried running its examples, which worked flawlessly.
The problems start as soon as I try to move the flutter_sound code into the isolate created by the flutter_foreground_task package and start running the application:
MissingPluginException (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method resetPlugin on channel xyz.canardoux.flutter_sound_player))

I tried flutter clean as well as flutter pub cache clean combined with rebuilding the project after adding all dependencies. I tried WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized() and DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized() to no avail.
I know that running code in another isolate and code that is only not ignored in the building process via @pragma('vm:entry-point') can cause troubles when executing native code or plugins inside it.
How can I solve this exception? Currently, I only test it for Android, iOS will be a later problem.
To reproduce it, generate a new empty flutter project and replace the main.dart contents with the following code based on the official flutter_foreground_task example (I can further shorten in on request). The corresponding AndroidManifest.xml is located beneath the code. Also add the following three packages to the project's pubspec.yaml: flutter_foreground_task, flutter_sound, and permission_handler.
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_foreground_task/flutter_foreground_task.dart';
import 'package:flutter_sound/flutter_sound.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

void main() {
  FlutterForegroundTask.initCommunicationPort();
  runApp(const ExampleApp());
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void startCallback() {
  FlutterForegroundTask.setTaskHandler(MyTaskHandler());
}

class MyTaskHandler extends TaskHandler {
  static const String incrementCountCommand = 'incrementCount';

  int _count = 0;

  FlutterSoundRecorder _recorder = FlutterSoundRecorder();
  FlutterSoundPlayer _player = FlutterSoundPlayer();

  final StreamController<Uint8List> _streamController =
      StreamController<Uint8List>.broadcast();

  void _incrementCount() {
    _count++;

    FlutterForegroundTask.updateService(
      notificationTitle: 'Hello MyTaskHandler :)',
      notificationText: 'count: $_count',
    );

    FlutterForegroundTask.sendDataToMain(_count);
  }

  @override
  void onStart(DateTime timestamp) async {
    print('onStart');
    _incrementCount();
    await _player.openPlayer();
    await _player.setVolume(1.0);
    await _recorder.openRecorder();
    _streamController.stream.listen((Uint8List food) {
      if (_player.isPlaying) {
        _player.foodSink!.add(FoodData(food));
      }
    });
    await _player.startPlayerFromStream(
      sampleRate: 44100,
      whenFinished: _streamController.close,
    );
    await _recorder.startRecorder(
      toStream: _streamController.sink,
      codec: Codec.pcm16,
      sampleRate: 44100,
    );
  }

  @override
  void onRepeatEvent(DateTime timestamp) {
    _incrementCount();
  }

  @override
  void onDestroy(DateTime timestamp) async {
    print('onDestroy');
    await _player.stopPlayer();
    await _player.closePlayer();

    await _recorder.stopRecorder();
    await _recorder.closeRecorder();

    await _streamController.close();
  }

  @override
  void onReceiveData(Object data) {
    print('onReceiveData: $data');
    if (data == incrementCountCommand) {
      _incrementCount();
    }
  }

  @override
  void onNotificationButtonPressed(String id) {
    print('onNotificationButtonPressed: $id');
  }

  @override
  void onNotificationPressed() {
    FlutterForegroundTask.launchApp('/');
    print('onNotificationPressed');
  }

  @override
  void onNotificationDismissed() {
    print('onNotificationDismissed');
  }
}

class ExampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const ExampleApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => const ExamplePage(),
      },
      initialRoute: '/',
    );
  }
}

class ExamplePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExamplePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _ExamplePageState();
}

class _ExamplePageState extends State<ExamplePage> {
  final ValueNotifier<Object?> _receivedTaskData = ValueNotifier(null);

  Future<void> _requestPermissions() async {
    final NotificationPermission notificationPermission =
        await FlutterForegroundTask.checkNotificationPermission();
    if (notificationPermission != NotificationPermission.granted) {
      await FlutterForegroundTask.requestNotificationPermission();
    }
    //microphone permission
    final PermissionStatus microphonePermission =
        await Permission.microphone.status;

    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      if (!await FlutterForegroundTask.canDrawOverlays) {
        await FlutterForegroundTask.openSystemAlertWindowSettings();
      }

      if (!await FlutterForegroundTask.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations) {
        await FlutterForegroundTask.requestIgnoreBatteryOptimization();
      }

      if (!await FlutterForegroundTask.canScheduleExactAlarms) {
        await FlutterForegroundTask.openAlarmsAndRemindersSettings();
      }
    }
  }

  void _initService() {
    FlutterForegroundTask.init(
      androidNotificationOptions: AndroidNotificationOptions(
        channelId: 'foreground_service',
        channelName: 'Foreground Service Notification',
        channelDescription:
            'This notification appears when the foreground service is running.',
        channelImportance: NotificationChannelImportance.LOW,
        priority: NotificationPriority.LOW,
      ),
      iosNotificationOptions: const IOSNotificationOptions(
        showNotification: false,
        playSound: false,
      ),
      foregroundTaskOptions: ForegroundTaskOptions(
        eventAction: ForegroundTaskEventAction.repeat(5000),
        autoRunOnBoot: true,
        autoRunOnMyPackageReplaced: true,
        allowWakeLock: true,
        allowWifiLock: true,
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<ServiceRequestResult> _startService() async {
    if (await FlutterForegroundTask.isRunningService) {
      return FlutterForegroundTask.restartService();
    } else {
      return FlutterForegroundTask.startService(
        serviceId: 256,
        notificationTitle: 'Foreground Service is running',
        notificationText: 'Tap to return to the app',
        notificationIcon: null,
        notificationButtons: [
          const NotificationButton(id: 'btn_hello', text: 'hello'),
        ],
        callback: startCallback,
      );
    }
  }

  Future<ServiceRequestResult> _stopService() async {
    return FlutterForegroundTask.stopService();
  }

  void _onReceiveTaskData(Object data) {
    print('onReceiveTaskData: $data');
    _receivedTaskData.value = data;
  }

  void _incrementCount() {
    FlutterForegroundTask.sendDataToTask(MyTaskHandler.incrementCountCommand);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FlutterForegroundTask.addTaskDataCallback(_onReceiveTaskData);

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _requestPermissions();
      _initService();
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    FlutterForegroundTask.removeTaskDataCallback(_onReceiveTaskData);
    _receivedTaskData.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WithForegroundTask(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Flutter Foreground Task'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: _buildContentView(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildContentView() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(child: _buildCommunicationText()),
        _buildServiceControlButtons(),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCommunicationText() {
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: _receivedTaskData,
      builder: (context, data, _) {
        return Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              const Text('You received data from TaskHandler:'),
              Text('$data', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildServiceControlButtons() {
    buttonBuilder(String text, {VoidCallback? onPressed}) {
      return ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: onPressed,
        child: Text(text),
      );
    }

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          buttonBuilder('start service', onPressed: _startService),
          buttonBuilder('stop service', onPressed: _stopService),
          buttonBuilder('increment count', onPressed: _incrementCount),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MICROPHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK" />
    <!-- required -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <!-- foregroundServiceType: dataSync -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_DATA_SYNC" />
    <!-- foregroundServiceType: remoteMessaging -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_REMOTE_MESSAGING" />
    <application
        tools:replace="android:icon, android:label"
        android:label="flutter_isolate_test"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <!-- Warning: Do not change service name. -->
        <service 
            android:name="com.pravera.flutter_foreground_task.service.ForegroundService"
            android:foregroundServiceType="dataSync|remoteMessaging"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
    <!-- Required to query activities that can process text, see:
         https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility and
         https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT.

         In particular, this is used by the Flutter engine in io.flutter.plugin.text.ProcessTextPlugin. -->
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>


My solution was to wait for 1 second after I called WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized() and DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized() for Flutter to load everything in the background.
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();

// DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE.
// Without this Flutter Foreground Task will not work
// Otherwise, it shows this error message:
// `No implementation found for method "start" on channel "flutter_foreground_task"/background`
await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));

